# What's the reason of using useStore in vuex4

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vuex4

Hey would like to know the reason :)

Why import the useStore function instead of importing directly the /store/index.js file
https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html

[image: image.png]
[image: image.png]
Seems like it does the same

Answer (score 1):

`useStore` uses `inject` (provide/inject api) to access the store. This means that passing the store from another file/dependency is not needed. It is preferred only because it is consistent thematically with the composition API (hooks).

Comment: So just to confirm, it's basically the same, but to use useStore is just a convention?

Comment: yes, as you can see, the end result is the same